# How do I read CFG from a file encoded in UTF-8 using nltk.data.load() ? ASCII files works fine but UTF-8 encoded file gives an error

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, nltk

I am trying to load a Context-free grammar by using nltk.data.load(). The grammar consists of texts other than English and has to be encoded in UTF-8 format. nltk.data.load() works fine for files in ASCII format but would not work for files in UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the help?

```
>>> help(nltk.data.load)
```

would have shown you this:

> load(resource_url, format='auto', cache=True, verbose=False,
>   logic_parser=None, fstruct_reader=None, **encoding=None**)
>       Load a given resource from the NLTK data package.  The following
>       resource formats are currently supported:
>    ...

So, add `encoding="utf-8"` to your call to `nltk.data.load()`. (I would have tried it before even checking the help, because how else would you specify the encoding?)

Comment: I have already tried: `manipuri_grammar = nltk.data.load(grammar_file,'cfg','utf-8')`,
Error:
`ValueError: Unable to parse line 1: S -> NP VP`,
`Expected a nonterminal, found: S -> NP VP`,
If I save the file in ASCII, it works. The problem comes up when I save the file as UTF-8.